# Filter Excel spreadsheet values from file

Tags: excel, csv, filter, spreadsheet, sccm

I want to be able to filter column values in an excel spreadsheet from values of an external file.

For example: Column A lists a bunch of programs running on a computer. I have a white-list of "approved programs" in a .txt or .csv file.

I want to write a script that will delete entries from "Column A" if the cell contains a value matching one of the entries in the .csv file.

E.g.: "Column A" contains hundreds of entries from "Adobe" to "Xerox". I have my list of "approved software" that contains Adobe and Xerox. I would like Excel to search for entries containing Adobe and Xerox from "Column A" leaving only un-approved software.

For those wondering... I am getting my data from SCCM and I am trying to find a way to create reports for workstations with un-approved software. If there is an easier way than dumping it to an Excel Spreadsheet, I would appreciate the input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your whitelist contains names that are exactly the same as any to-be-approved names in Column A, transfer your whitelist into Excel as a column of values, giving it a range name of say "whitelist". Assuming that the column A values start in row 2, use the MATCH function to identify in column B whether the item appears on the white list or not. A suitable expression for cell B2 would be

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,whitelist,0)),"Unapproved","Approved")
```

Copy this down column B for all other entries. Col B will read either "Approved" or "Unapproved" according to whether corresponding value is on white list or not.

You can now apply Excel's data filter to the table in columns A and B to get a list of  Unapproved items which can be pasted to a suitable location.

Depending on your VBA skills you can automate this either by writing your own code or using the macro recorder.

The initial assumption is important - if it is not true then you will end up with a lot of false unapproveds.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not able to replicate your suggestion. I am admittedly not the best in excel. Any suggestions?

I am wondering if this might be easier done/manipulated in python?

Comment: Not an answer as it doesn't specifically address the question, but it did work and is a valuable technique - thanks!